# Different result for to_number in Order By clause in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, type-conversion, ora-01722

I have two queries which give error `ORA-01722: invalid number` when trying to convert `CHAR` to `NUMBER`.

```
SELECT to_number('NYC TERM') FROM dual;

WITH
  x AS (SELECT 'NYC TERM' AS col FROM dual
          UNION
        SELECT '33' FROM dual)
SELECT *
  FROM X
 ORDER BY to_number(col);
```

If I remove the second `SELECT` in `UNION` query works fine. Why is it behaving different?

The issue is when I run a query as a whole returning other rows it gives error, but when I run for just that particular record which has this kind of data it acts fine.

```
 WITH
   x AS (SELECT 'NYC TERM' AS col FROM dual)
 SELECT * FROM X ORDER BY to_number(col);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit long for a comment.

I think what is happening is that Oracle is short-circuiting the `order by` for performance reasons.  With only one row, there is no need to sort at all, so even the key doesn't get evaluated.  This is perhaps more clearly seen in this absurd example:

```
 WITH x AS (SELECT 'NYT TERM' AS col FROM DUAL)
 SELECT * FROM X ORDER BY length(col) / 0;
```

This returns one row with one column, `'NYT TERM'`.  No error.

I suppose this is considered a "feature".

Comment: Thank you so much for replying.That's really absurd.It is difficult to explain as to why it's happening.

Comment: @Raja . . . Not at all.  With only one record, there is no need to evaluate the expression for the `order by` key.  This is a performance gain . . . although in the admittedly minor case of evaluating a key and sorting one record.